# Animated image on CardView with Relative/Linear Layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I want to have an animation that I want to play on a `CardView`. I placed an `ImageView` in that view with `LinearLayout` and it shows that it's on there but the animation is simply not playing. I have checked a lot of other posts of similar issues and try to implement the fixes but it won't do it. I checked if my images are all the same, which they are not, and the naming of things again and again. I feel like I'm missing something super simple but just could not resolve what.

This is my activity_lock_reminder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/trans_black"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.antbicycle.project.antbicycle.LockReminderActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/greenTintWhite"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Remember to Lock Your Bike"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lockAnimation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/animation"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/reminder_advisory"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/reminder_note"
                android:textColor="@color/grayOut"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_dismissReminder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="dismiss"
                android:background="@drawable/button_green_round"
                android:textColor="@color/ln_colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my LockReminder.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Animatable;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class LockReminderActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_reminder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        if(hasFocus){
            final ImageView anm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lockAnimation);
            ((Animatable) anm.getDrawable()).start();
        }
    }
}
```

And my animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true"
    android:visible="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_0" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_1" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_2" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_3" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_4" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_5" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_6" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_7" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_8" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_9" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_10" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_11" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_12" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_13" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_14" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_15" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_16" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_17" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_18" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_19" android:duration="200"/>
</animation-list>
```

This is the Card View after it shows up:

[image]

The lock is just a still image instead of going through the animate-list.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable

```
 // Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
 // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lockAnimation);
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);

 // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: I double checked I don't see where did I call R.drawable.spin_animation. I looked at all the code I posted and did not find it

Comment: I might've had some sort of dyslexia when reading the docs and your code. That example should work however.